# Select records based on priority

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, query, sql-server-2017

I have data stored as:

```
TestId  | Priority |
--------+-----+-----
test103 | 2        | 
test104 | 2        | 
test105 | 1        | 
test106 | 0        | 
test107 | 1        | 
test108 | 2        | 
test109 | 0        | 
test110 | 1        | 
test111 | 1        |
```

I want to be able to select top 2 based on priority like below.

```
TestId  | Priority |
--------+-----+----- 
test106 | 0        | 
test109 | 0        |
```

We have over a million records and I would like a query that is more efficient in terms on performance. Please any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What happens when the testid goes over 999? Version of SQL Server?

Comment: please ignore the testid column as we use an incremental integer, so we could have 1, 2, 3,4 and so on. The version is 2017

Comment: Unless I've missed something obvious, what's wrong with select * from tab order by priority, testid;?

Comment: Performance is a problem, takes about 17sec. Was asking for a better way to approach the query that is performant

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: You just need an index that covers your query.

Comment: Is the highest `Priority` always 0? Is there always at least two records in the table with `Priority` = 0? Which "*top 2*" records would you want when there are 3 records with `Priority` = 0?

Answer (score 1):

To get TOP 2 from the table described above:

```
SELECT TOP(2) TestID, Priority FROM test_table ORDER BY Priority ASC
```

**BUT**
You need to have an index on the table with definition as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_test_table ON test_table (Priority) INCLUDE (TestId);
```

With this index, the query reads 2 rows and is finished as the execution plan below shows. This applies **regardless of table size**. TOP operator effectively works as "execution terminator" here, because as soon as he gets 2 rows from the index scan operator, the query is finished.

[image: Execution plan resulting from tests of OP's problem]

As J.D. said, if there are more than 2 results with lowest prioriry (given you search for lowest priority), these aren't returned, but I bet you are aware of that.